# C++, align value

Tags: c++, alignment

I have created a login form in C++. I need to enter user name next to "User Name" label. But the cursor is always left aligned. Is there anyway to do this?

This is my code and snap of the output.

```
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void loginForm()
{
string userName;
string passWord;


system("mode con:cols=110 lines=37");
CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX cfi;
cfi.cbSize = sizeof cfi;
cfi.nFont = 0;
cfi.dwFontSize.X = 0;
cfi.dwFontSize.Y = 18;
cfi.FontFamily = FF_DONTCARE;
cfi.FontWeight = FW_NORMAL;
system ("cls");
system("color 0A");

cout<< endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << setw(85)<<"****************************************************************" << endl
<< setw(85)<<"|Smiling Tooth Hospital Patient Registration and Booking System|"  << endl
<< setw(85)<<"****************************************************************" << endl;

cout<< endl << endl << endl << endl << setw(75)<<"Please Enter User Name & Password to Continue"<< endl << endl << endl;
cout<<setw(56) << "User Name: " << endl;
cin >> setw(100) >> userName;
cout<<setw(55) << "Password: " << endl;
system ("pause");


}

int main ()
{
    loginForm();
    return 0;

}
```

[image]

Comment: Remove the `<< endl` from the line.

Comment: Have you tried using [the justification I/O manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left)?

Comment: thanks. I really missed it. thank you!!!